# Replacement for Jquery Select2 in Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, jquery-select2, flask-admin

I  just realize that my select2 field in Flask-Admin, is really loading all the contents of the select2 field in the HTML. So, it's very slow (I have 4k items in the list). Can't find any configuration such as lazy loading there.   Or, is there better alternative for Flask-Admin to be use to replace Select2?

Comment: You can do partial loading using [Ajax](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just realize select2 support this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just realize select2 did support this lazy loading feature.http://select2.github.io/select2/ `Infinite Scroll with Remote Data`